# Why was the demon after the little girl?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wailing

I just watched [***The Wailing***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5215952/) and I am not sure why was demon after the little girl.

Two possibilities are, first, as someone said in the movie that he was catching fishes in the village and thus was random.

Second, the woman in white said that it was because her father committed a sin of suspecting the demon and going after him, but Jong-goo rejected that saying that it started before that?

So what is the exact reason of the demon killing people in the village and especially going after Hyo-jin.

Answer (score 2):

This is just my subjective interpretation, but I think the real villain behind all this chaos is actually the woman in white, and that the Japanese man is actually a Buddhist monk trying to save the villagers.

I think the woman in white is actually a Catholic woman martyred during the Joseon Dynasty, and the reason why she's doing these things is because she was driven mad by the powers given to her by God after her martyrdom. She was trying to trap 'Murder' itself, which is an impossible task.

I think Jong-goo is just one of the random unlucky people who got targeted, but I think the director is also saying he's guilty of discrimination and xenophobia, because he ended up causing the death of the Japanese monk, who was innocent all along.

For a more detailed explanation you might want to check out some posts I made on Tumblr.

http://accidentsofdesign.tumblr.com/post/170054300456/the-wailing-analysis-part-1-of-3
http://accidentsofdesign.tumblr.com/post/170109725191/the-wailing-analysis-part-2-of-3
http://accidentsofdesign.tumblr.com/post/171012206986/the-wailing-analysis-part-3-of-3